# Fiddler exception different than C# exception

Tags: c#, exception, fiddler

We contact an Azure webservice to send over certain information.

When I send the request from C#, the exception provides the stacktrace from the sending side.

When I send the request from Fiddler, the exception provides the stacktrace from the receiving side.

I want to get the receiving side stacktrace in the logging as it's more usefull. Any ideas on how to do this? To my knowledge Fiddler uses HttpRequest as does C#

Code in C#:

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Adrewss);
...

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();

catch (Exception ex)
{
     logEntry.Details = ex.ToString();
```

Let me know if more info is needed!

So C# ex =

500) Internal Server Error.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Fiddler ex:

{"Post":"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at Test.Gateway.Models.Process.Transformer.GetTypeCode(String Type)\r\n etc

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access

Comment: Url of an azure web service

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler doesn't use HTTPWebRequest at all, it talks to a raw socket. I'm guessing you're showing the raw text from the Response's body in Fiddler, while you're relying upon the exception (rather than the response body text) in your .NET code.

Comment: Correct, used the following code to fix it:

if(ex is WebException)
                {
                    var webEx = (WebException)ex;

                    if (webEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                    {
                        using (Stream responseStream = webEx.Response.GetResponseStream())
                        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            additionalErrorInfo = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }